# Mysql port already in use

Tags: mysql

```
180718 12:43:04 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
180718 12:43:04 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
180718 12:43:04 [ERROR] Aborting
```

is there any solution for it? Mysql is running on windows based server.
Please give the best solution..

Answer (score 12):

Either a second instance of MySQL or another service is running on port 3306.

You can either stop the service which is running on port 3306 by

getting the process id of that service:

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "3306"
```

and then killing that process (e.g. for process id `1234`):

```
taskkill /pid 1234 /f
```

or run MySQL on a different port.

Comment: Sir, it is again show this error after apply your command and service is again stop. when i try to start it. it show 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

I had also faced the problem. I stopped the "docker desktop" app(you have to stop from the app if you stop it from the task manager then it will restart automatically).it works for me.

Comment: Had the same problem and indeed was docker desktop. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I solved it by executing the command to get the PID using the same port:

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "3306"
```

After you get the PID, go to Task manager > Services and right click on the service with the same PID, and press stop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because mysql workbench uses port:3306 when you try to connect it through PhP platform and the port can only be used by one app so xampp is deprived of it, the reason it's aborting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).